# Connecting to an Azure database with a hyphen in its name

Tags: python, sql-server, azure

I have an azure sql server instance containing a database which has a hyphen in its name like "database-name".

I am trying to connect via a python script and having some issues with it.

In the script when I use the connection string like this:

```
"Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=serveraddress;Database=database-name;UID=username;PWD=password;"
```

I get the following error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'name'.
```

I figured this may be caused by the hyphen and changed the connection string to this instead:

```
"Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=serveraddress;Database=[database-name];UID=username;PWD=password;"
```

But I get an error like this:

```
Cannot open database "[database-name]" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

however I am able to login with the same user from SSMS.

Can this be permission related issue?

Comment: _Incorrect syntax near 'name'_ isn't likely to be occurring during the connection phase. Are you also trying to use the database name as part of the command/script you're trying to execute? e.g.: does your script include something like `use database-name;` or `select * from database-name.schema.table`?

Comment: Square brackets around the database name _in the connection string_ cannot help here. It appears the connection is working fine. The problem is your script needs to insulate itself from errors due to problematic database, object, and column names. Make sure you use QUOTENAME() when building object names because just manually adding [ and ] is less secure.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce your scenario on my end and got results like the below:-***

I created one Azure SQL server and database both with hyphen in their names like below:-

[image]

Make sure you add your client IP access to your Azure SQL database like below:-

[image]

I populated Azure SQL Database with one table and its entities.

[image]

[image]

Tried the below code to connect Azure SQL DB with python, Make sure your connection string format is correct as per the code below:-
You can validate the connection string from your Azure Portal like below:-

[image]

Code:-

```py
import pyodbc

  

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'

'Server=tcp:valley-server.database.windows.net,1433;'

'Database=valley-db;'

'Uid=siliconserver;'

'Pwd=xxxxxx@123')

  
  

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM StudentReviews')

  

for  i  in  cursor:

print(i)

  

cursor.close()

conn.close()
```

[image]

SQL command executed successfully by connecting to Azure-SQL DB. Make sure the ODBC package is installed in your machine from where you’re executing the code. And the server or Database name has correct spelling or syntax.